# Tarckpad scroll direction

Tags: settings, touchpad

Using Elementary OS as VM with Parallels. So far no severe problems. But the trackpad scrolling direction setting has no effect. I'd like to use "natural scrolling" (My German installation: "Natürliches Scrollen"). No matter of the swtch selection, scrolling is always in the same (not desired) mode (i.e. moving down moves window content upwards). Hardware is MAcbook Pro with integrated trackpad...
Any idea???

Thx in advance,
- dx05

Comment: I don"t want post answer because I am not sure this link can resolve your problem. Maybe you can read this article https://int3ractive.com/2018/09/make-the-best-of-MacBook-touchpad-on-Ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer for VM, but for bare metal Elementary Tweaks has a natural scrolling setting, I don't know why it wouldn't work with VM, also.

https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks

Don't forget `sudo apt install software-properties-common` if you need to add the PPA.